# Print out TableView Data as table (not image) with custom formating using java

Tags: java, javafx, printing, tableview, observablelist

Please help if you can otherwise skip.

I am developing a software using `JavaFX`. I have a `TableView` which I want to printout in Landscape A4 page with custom formatting. My table will contain huge rows, so it is necessary that the table must split into multiple pages. I have searched on the web but not getting the proper solution. I found many posts which does not meet my requirement.

I have a jfx table created with observable list like this:

[image: JFX TableView]

And I want to print this table as like below:

[image: Printout]

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This is a non-trivial task. Your best bet is to use a library that generates a known document format from the data backing the table view. I've never used Jasper Reports, but it probably has the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done with Jasper Reports Library. I found my solution using this library.